# Can someone mention few good web sites to learn theravada Buddhism?

Tags: theravada, learning-materials

I run a Buddhist blog with daily updates and i am facing a bit of trouble finding sources for it as i try to update it everyday with at least a single new article or a book everyday.

I am already using "Accesstoinsight.org" as a primary source of good materials.

Can you please mention a few more such good web sites?

Answer (score 7):

[A Handful of Leaves](http://www.ahandfulofleaves.org/) has [books](http://www.ahandfulofleaves.org/Library.html) and [papers](http://www.ahandfulofleaves.org/Articles.html). Also http://www.dhammatalks.net/, http://www.wisdomlib.org/, http://www.buddhanet.net/ (multiple authors) and http://www.dhammatalks.org/ (by [Thanissaro Bhikkhu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanissaro_Bhikkhu)), http://www.aimwell.org/. In addition https://archive.org/ does have many old Buddhist books. http://static.sirimangalo.org/pdf/ has also got scans of some old books.

http://www.abhidhamma.com/ has many Abhidhamma books.

Also there is Piya Tan's website - http://dharmafarer.org/ which has essays and traslations.

Also VRI ([Ledi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ledi_Sayadaw) / [U Ba Khin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba_Khin) tradition) has couple of online resource:

- http://www.vridhamma.org/Research-Index
- http://www.vridhamma.org/Research
- http://www.vridhamma.org/Online-Books-and-Pamphlets

Also you can look into magazine like: https://tricycle.org/, http://www.mindful.org/, http://www.lionsroar.com/ to get material.

Also have a look at: https://what-buddha-said.net/. This is a blog which posts something new on Buddhism nearly every day.

Also following are other sites like http://www.accesstoinsight.org/: https://suttacentral.net/, http://www.tipitaka.org/, http://newguide.org/

Comment: Thank you for the answer dear friend,this will help many to learn the teaching and i share that good karma will you. please mention any more sites or books you can recommend as well because it will be of great help to me and a dhamma gift fore many others. May the triple gems bless you.  Namo Buddhaya!

Answer (score 3):

https://suttacentral.net/ offers a more comprehensive collection of the Tripitaka, in many languages too!

Comment: Thank you for the answer dear friend,this will help many to learn the teaching and i share that good karma will you. please mention any more sites or books you can recommend as well because it will be of great help to me and a dhamma gift fore many others. May the triple gems bless you.  Namo Buddhaya!